# Impact of high TPS on database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have an application which is very actively read/write database, especially during some specific load bursts moments. Some metrics:

- CPU user time goes doubles up from 25% to 50%
- high write rate ~700MB/s vs. ~250MB/s in normal conditions
- Transactions increase to 15K ops/s vs. 3K ops/s in normal conditions.

For context, database is fairly large, ~20Tb disk, ~100 tables which are read/write intensively. Application is executing OLTP workload with a small scoped transactions (no batching).

Machine specs are IO2 EBS volume, 30k iops, 64CPU & 500Gb RAM.

During mentioned peak moments I observed:

1. Increased **SyncRep - IPC - active wait events, and as a result - increasing queries latency.** What this might be related to? Does it mean that my connection to a replica saturated or replica overloaded? What are specific metrics I should look into to asses this issue?
2. Increased **LockManager - LWLock - active**, any suggestions why this might occur?
3. **High TPS on database**. I suspect that reducing TPS by batching database inserts to a single transaction will reduce a load on a database and reduce latency, but are there some suggestions regarding possible impact that might bring? I.e. CPU load reduced x2, write rate reduced, etc.? Maybe based on experience one can suggest what is a performance to be expected?

Thanks!

Comment: More transactions typically mean more I/O load. Waiting for the lock manager signifies contention. "SyncRep" means that you have synchronous replication, so you won't ever get very high TPS. This all sounds very normal.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks! What about that TPS part I mentioned, do you think it's worth activity to attempt batch queries into single transaction? any reference to some benchmarks you can suggest to review?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you mentioned "Waiting for the lock manager signifies contention" - what are the good stats to identify tables (?) that bring this contention? we can a setup where we have a lot of "data tables" (e.g. customer) and FK on "master data tables" (e.g. purchased product). can this be an issue?

Comment: Use transactions to bundle statements that must be bundled together for data consistency, otherwise you could get problems with deadlocks. Have a look at the parameter `synchronous_commit` for performance.

Comment: With that vague information, nothing definite can be said.